# How to update and set values based on multiple joins in select statment?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to update a column prtnum and revlvl in table invdtl based on value from select statment, here is the code

```
update invdtl set invdtl.prtnum = usr_prtmst_xref.prtnum,invdtl.revlvl =   
usr_prtmst_xref.colnam ([select                                   
invdtl.prtnum,usr_prtmst_xref.prtnum AS      
crossref,invdtl.revlvl,aremst.arecod,aremst.fwiflg from invdtl
join usr_prtmst_xref 
on usr_prtmst_xref.prtnum = usr_prtmst_xref.prtnum
join invsub
join invlod
join locmst
join aremst 
on aremst.arecod = locmst.arecod
and aremst.wh_id = locmst.wh_id 
on locmst.stoloc = invlod.stoloc
and locmst.wh_id = invlod.wh_id 
on invlod.lodnum = invsub.lodnum 
on invsub.subnum = invdtl.subnum where aremst.arecod = 'EXPR' or      
aremst.fwiflg = '1' and rownum <2])
```

I want to copy two values prtnum and revlvl that are returned by select statement but there is some syntax issue.

Comment: if you have error please show your exact error message

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: @scaisEdge error is unexpected token =

Comment: im using oracle, actually the tool i am working on is moca client which has a bit different sysntax for SQL.

Comment: you have tagged  you question  ... with mysql  ..  ... please post only the right tab ..

Comment: @scaisEdge actually there is syntax error in sql not the tool dependent error you can look for only query

Comment: i'm not in oracle  .. i looked  ato your question because is tagged mysql ... then change the tags  please ..

Answer (score 0):

> There are a bunch of errors here:
>
> 1. The syntax for a multi-column update is basically

```
    update blah
    set ( col1, col2 ) = ( select x, y
                            from
                            ...
                            )
```

> 2. The syntax for multiple joins is basically

```
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 
on t1.col = t2.col 
join table3 t2 on
t2.col = ...
```

> 3. Get ride of "["  and "]"
> 4. The predicate   `rownum<2` is probably to get around the message you received, something like "single row sub-query returns more than 1
>      row" Which this predicate "fixes" that problem, you are just getting
>      the first random row; probably not what you want. You probably need to
>      correlate  the sub-query with the update

I would fix these basic syntax errors and try again.